# Implementing Comparable, compareTo name clash: "have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other"

Tags: java, generics, overriding, comparable, erasure

I'd like to have a compareTo method that takes a Real (a class for working with arbitrarily large and precise real numbers [well, as long as it's less than 2^31 in length at the moment]) and a compareTo method that takes an Object, but Java isn't letting me and I'm not experienced enough to know why.

I just tried to modify the class to implement Comparable and I got these error messages below. I don't really understand what the error messages mean but I know it's got something to do with the horrible way I'm trying to give the class some flexibility with all the different method signatures for every single method I make, and I can fix it by removing the compareTo(Object other) method, but I would ideally like to keep it. So what I'm really asking is: Is there a way to make these error messages disappear without removing the compareTo(Object other) method and what exactly do these errors mean?

Also, I know there are already some built-in Java classes like BigInteger and things like that for what I'm trying to use this class for but I'm doing it for fun/satisfaction for use with Project Euler (https://projecteuler.net/).

```
Jake@Jake-PC /cygdrive/c/Users/Jake/Documents/Java/Mathematics
$ javac Real.java
Real.java:377: error: name clash: compareTo(Real) in Real overrides a method whose erasure is the same as another method, yet neither overrides the other
  public int compareTo(Real other)
             ^
  first method:  compareTo(Object) in Real
  second method: compareTo(T) in Comparable
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
Real.java:440: error: name clash: compareTo(Object) in Real and compareTo(T) in Comparable have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
  public int compareTo(Object other)
             ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
2 errors
```

These are the compareTo methods:

```
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Real other)
  {
    // Logic.
  }
  public int compareTo(char givenValue) 
  { return compareTo(new Real(givenValue)); }
  public int compareTo(char[] givenValue) 
  { return compareTo(new Real(givenValue)); }
  public int compareTo(char[] givenValue, int offset, int count) 
  { return compareTo(new Real(givenValue, offset, count)); }
  public int compareTo(double givenValue) 
  { return compareTo(new Real(givenValue)); }
  public int compareTo(float givenValue) 
  { return compareTo(new Real(givenValue)); }
  public int compareTo(int givenValue) 
  { return compareTo(new Real(givenValue)); }
  public int compareTo(long givenValue) 
  { return compareTo(new Real(givenValue)); }
  public int compareTo(Object other) 
  { return compareTo(new Real(other.toString())); }
```

and the constructors just in case you need them:

```
  public Real(String givenValue)
  {
    // Logic.
  }
  public Real(char givenValue) 
  { this(String.valueOf(givenValue)); }
  public Real(char[] givenValue) 
  { this(String.valueOf(givenValue)); }
  public Real(char[] givenValue, int offset, int count) 
  { this(String.valueOf(givenValue, offset, count)); }
  public Real(double givenValue) 
  { this(String.valueOf(givenValue)); }
  public Real(float givenValue) 
  { this(String.valueOf(givenValue)); }
  public Real(int givenValue) 
  { this(String.valueOf(givenValue)); }
  public Real(long givenValue) 
  { this(String.valueOf(givenValue)); }
  public Real(Object other) 
  { this(other.toString()); }
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The offending methods are:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Real other) { ... }

public int compareTo(Object other) { ... }
```

These methods have the same [*erasure*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), meaning that once the compiler strips out generic type information, there will no longer be a way to differentiate them at runtime.

Your options are to either remove the `compareTo(Object other)` overload, or for `Real` to implement `Comparable<Object>`.

Since it looks like the implementations of all your `compareTo` overloads just instantiate a new `Real` and pass it to `compareTo(Real)`, I'd suggest removing them and leaving that conversion up to the caller:

```
Real real = ...;
Object compared = ...;

Real comparedAsReal = new Real(compared);
int result = real.compareTo(comparedAsReal);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to be able to compare `Real` object to `Object`, you may just replace the `implements Comparable<Real>` with `implements Comparable<Object>`. This would be consistent with `Comparable<T>` javadoc which says that `<T> the type of objects that this object may be compared to`.

Then you just have to change your current code to :

```
// No more @Override
public int compareToReal(Real other)
{
  // Logic.
}
public int compareTo(char givenValue) 
{ return compareToReal(new Real(givenValue)); }
public int compareTo(char[] givenValue) 
{ return compareToReal(new Real(givenValue)); }
public int compareTo(char[] givenValue, int offset, int count) 
{ return compareToReal(new Real(givenValue, offset, count)); }
public int compareTo(double givenValue) 
{ return compareToReal(new Real(givenValue)); }
public int compareTo(float givenValue) 
{ return compareToReal(new Real(givenValue)); }
public int compareTo(int givenValue) 
{ return compareToReal(new Real(givenValue)); }
public int compareTo(long givenValue) 
{ return compareToReal(new Real(givenValue)); }
@Override
public int compareTo(Object other) 
{ return compareToReal(new Real(other.toString())); }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a side effect of **Java generics type-erasure**.

You are implementing a **generic interface**, Comparable, but this its unique method, once generic type erased will become *compareTo(Object)*, hence it clashes with your own *compareTo(Object)*.

Here is a minimal code to reproduce:

```
class Real implements Comparable<Real>
{
    public int compareTo(Object o)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Real o)
    {
        return 0;
    }       
}
```